# handle sound triggered on contact without SCNAudioSource

Tags: ios, audio, scenekit, audiotoolbox

How does one handle sound triggered on contact with other nodes in SceneKit without SCNAudioSource class (SCNAudioSource is only available in iOS9). What frameworks should be used, which are preferable?

I will be doing the following: I am just animating a box falling on the ground and than roll a few times. It would be nice if a could ad a realistic "hit" sound every time the box hits the ground.  I have also implemented a method that calculates the current linear and rotational speed so that I can link the volume level of a hit proportional to the speed of box at that time.

I was thinking I could use `physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBeginContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact)`and produce the sound in here, but I am a little sceptical, because this gets called really a lot.